# Magento 2: DHL Shipping Method Issue undefined

Tags: magento2.1

I have set Allowed All Countries & My Shipping Address Country is also Valid.

Product has also Weight.

What is missing i'm in Setting or what's Wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use different network, might be possible that the web services are blocked on your network which prevents requesting the shipping carrier servers and also check your credentials.

You can also check this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/167757/magento-2-fedex-dhl-usps-ups-exception-this-shipping-method-is-currently-unava) from where I found an answer of your question!